# What would be an anternative to Guice's FactoryModuleBuilder in plain Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a service which would act as an API (or as a façade). I'd like it to has its capabilities defined via an interface class but having the implementation of each method separated in different `Command` classes... but without having to create an actual class implementing the interface.

Let's say an example service:

```java
public interface FileSystem {
    public Long computeTotalStorageSpace();
    public Long computeUsedStorageSpace();
    public Set<File> find(Predicate<File>...filters);
    public Boolean delete(File file);
}
```

With an example command:

```java
public class ComputeTotalStorageSpaceCommand implements Command<Void, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long execute(Void void) { //.. }
}
```

I know Guice does something similar to this thanks to `com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder` but using Guice is currently not a valid option.

How else could this be done?

Comment: An interface with no implementation... are you looking for `@FunctionalInterface`? Your question is quite vague.

Comment: No, it contains more than a single method. I'm interested in decoupling each interface's method in separate command classes.